# How to align form elements next to image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to align a `label`, a `text-input` and an `X` sign next to each other using Bootstrap 4.

I managed to align the `label` and `text-input` but can't seem to do that with the `X` sign.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jptyuv5n/

How can we align that `X` sign next to the input field? What am I missing here?

```css
.collection {
  display: flex;
}

.collection img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.collection .form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.collection .form input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 collection">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796">
    <div class="form">
      <label>Text</label>
      <input type="text" name="text1">
      <span>X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 collection">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796">
    <div class="form">
      <label>Text</label>
      <input type="text" name="text2">
      <span>X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: I just saw in your question that you mentioned Bootstrap 4. Same result can be achieved with using bootstrap styles and 0 css lines from you.

The classes used in the snippet below are documented here: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#overview](http://Forms:%20Bootstrap)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 collection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796">
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
            <label>text</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">X</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**Old answer**:

You can wrap the `<input>` and the `<span>` holding `x` in a div and use flex on it.

```css
.collection {
  display: flex;
}

.collection img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.collection .form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  flex-direction: column; /* <- changed flex direction of form */
}

.collection .form input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-with-x { /* <- new classes added */
  display: flex; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 collection">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796">
      <div class="form">
        <label>Text</label>
        <div class="input-with-x"> <!-- <- new class used -->
        <input type="text" name="text2">
        <span>X</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Radical_Activity No problem! I just updated my answer to include a more "bootstrap'-y way of achieving same result.